# Не вставляются данные в таблицу

Tags: c#, база-данных, access

Написал вот такой код:

```
recordsTableAdapter.Insert(this.Text, PersonName, ResultWritter);
baseDataSet.AcceptChanges();
recordsTableAdapter.Update(baseDataSet.Records);
```

В таблице не добавляются соответствующая строка, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: в чем угодно. Например, в SQL запросе.

Comment: OleDB адаптер, запросы только через адаптеры таблиц других нет.

Comment: Exception так же нет.

Comment: Заметил что теперь данные пишутся в базу в папке debug а раньше писались в базы в папке с остальными файлами проекта. Ничего не менял как такое могло произойти?

Comment: `а раньше писались в базы в папке с остальными файлами проекта` вы уверены в этом? Либо раньше был прописан абсолютный путь до БД, а теперь прописан относительный, либо раньше оно писалось туда же, куда сейчас пишется.